# problem with python kivy - screen refresh issues

Tags: python, kivy, refresh, screen

I have problem with kivy in python.
I started tutorial at kivy website - pong in kivy. But there was a little problem - when i created a ball on screen and i wanted to move it - at the screen was created many balls - one ball for for one frame and they did not disappear.
I gave up and i started a 2nd tutorial on youtube - creating login screen. But i have the same problem with animation of screen change.
all you need to see is at the movie (youtube):

https://youtu.be/xXWq5XgQPnE

https://youtu.be/U6sKKLRD6Vk

there is the code of login screen :

python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("kvfile.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMainApp().run()
```

kivy file:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0


WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:


<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Name:"
            TextInput:
                id: uname
                multilane: False
            Label:
                text: "Password:"
            TextInput:
                id: upass
                multilane: False
        Button:
            text: "Log in"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"
<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    Button:
        text: "Go back"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "y": 0.2}
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.2
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
```

i have no idea what to do. any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your screens a name.

```
WindowManager:

    MainWindow:
        name: 'main'

    SecondWindow:
        name 'second'
```

And instead of calling `app.root.current` try calling `root.manager.current`

Here is some sample code that works on my computer...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_string(
    """
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
        name: 'main'
    SecondWindow:
        name: 'second'


<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Name:"
            TextInput:
                id: uname
                multilane: False
            Label:
                text: "Password:"
            TextInput:
                id: upass
                multilane: False
        Button:
            text: "Log in"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "second"
<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    Button:
        text: "Go back"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "y": 0.2}
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.2
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = "main"
"""
)


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Comment: Instead of calling `app.root.current` try calling `root.manager.current` (see edited answer)

Comment: i pasted your code i i have the same problem. i think the problem isnt in kivy but it's smth wrong in my options or smth.. i don't know. i tried other codes i found at tutorials and the same result. it's looks like there is the problem with screen refreshing.

i have tried reinstall kivy but no result too.